# change focus color while typing in input

Tags: javascript, css

Suppose i have a code that validates the username

```
 oValidationManager.sUsername = document.getElementById('username');

 validateUsername: function () {
                oValidationManager.sUsername.addEventListener('focus', function(event){
                    oValidationManager.sUsername.style.borderColor = '#FF0000';
                    oValidationManager.sUsername.style.boxShadow = 'inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6)';
                });
                oValidationManager.sUsername.addEventListener('blur', function(){
                    oValidationManager.sUsername.style.borderColor = '';
                    oValidationManager.sUsername.style.boxShadow = '';
                });
                if (oValidationManager.sUsername.value === '') {
                    oValidationManager.sShowUsernameError.innerHTML = oValidationManager.aErrorMsg.username.required;
                }  else {

                    oValidationManager.sUsername.addEventListener('focus', function(event){
                        oValidationManager.sUsername.style.borderColor = '#00FF00';
                        oValidationManager.sUsername.style.boxShadow = 'inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.6)';
                    });
                    oValidationManager.sShowUsernameError.innerHTML = '';
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            },
```

What I want to happen is to change the focus color if the field is valid even when the user is typing. Using the code above i can get the result however I need to click somewhere to see the updated focus color it is not being updated while typing.

Comment: are u expecting like this:https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_invalid

Comment: yes sir.........

Comment: you already have the answer in the above comment. instead of border add `background-color: red;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this without event listeners. Rather than changing the css properties directly try adding and removing classes. Do your error check and if there is one add a class like `.invalid` to the input. Then just have a different style for that class.

CSS:

```css
.input-field{
   border: 2px solid transparent;
}

.input-field:focus{
   border-color: blue;
}

.input-field.invalid:focus{
   border-color: red;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<input type="text" class="input-field"/>
```

JS:

```js
let myInput = document.querySelector(".input-field");

if(/*Something is wrong*/){
   myInput.classlist.add("invalid");
}else{
   myInput.classlist.remove("invalid");
}
```

Comment: can you provide an example?

Comment: @Beginner I updated my answer to make it super clear

Answer (score 0):

```css
input:invalid {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="email">
```